# Anaconda environment has different versions for numpy and numpy-base

Tags: python, numpy, version-control, anaconda, conda

I have two Python 3.7.11 environments managed by Anaconda, and I'm trying to sort out reproducibility issues between the two.
I've pinpointed those issues to `numpy` versions, and thus I've cloned my base environment to gradually upgrade `numpy` to find where they stem from.
While comparing versions between both environments, I've realized that the first one has both `numpy` and `numpy-base` listed, which apparently [happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50699252/anaconda-environment-installing-packages-numpy-base). However, `numpy` and `numpy-base` have different versions. If I run `conda list numpy`, I get the following :

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
numpy                     1.21.2                   pypi_0    pypi
numpy-base                1.16.5           py37hde5b4d6_0
```

While the same command within my second environment, in which I've upgraded and downgraded numpy several times, returns :

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
numpy                     1.16.5                   pypi_0    pypi
numpy-base                1.16.5           py37hde5b4d6_0
```

Printing `numpy.__version__` in both environments returns `1.16.5`.

However, `pip show numpy` returns `1.21.2` for the first environment and `1.16.5` for the second, as `pip show numpy-base` apparently doesn't work.

From what I've read in the answer I've linked above, it seems that `numpy-base` is the version actually doing calculations, but as my results aren't reproducible between the two environments, could it cause issues ?

Comment: I feel like this is an artifact from mixing pypi and conda packages. You can probably save yourself a lot of sanity when installing numpy from conda repositories exclusively :-)

Comment: @cel This does seem to be an issue, I was at least able to reproduce the layout of the first environment by installing 1.21.2 with pypi and then 1.16.5 with conda. Now I just have to find a way to get reproducible results with a clean install !